# migrating a site Boonex Dolphin?

Tags: boonex-dolphin

Anyone have idea how to solve the following error in local site works great, but just upload it displays the following:

Warning: Please contact support about failure in /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/design.inc.php on line 139

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/design.inc.php:139) in /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/classes/BxDolTemplate.php on line 1618

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/design.inc.php:139) in /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/design.inc.php on line 133

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/connectt/_labs/comet/dolphin2/inc/design.inc.php on line 134

Answer (score 1):

I think your design.inc.php is screwed up or maybe got corrupted. You should try to replace it with a new one from your dolphin zip.